# Insert json with strings with quotes within them to Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have some JSON I'm trying to insert into a Postgres database but I can't manage to properly escape the quotes, here's my code

```
insert into Product_Templates (product) values( '{
"template_id": "OSBSheet",
"name":'Exterior Wall Using 2\"x4\"x96\" Studs, Double Top Plate'
```

}

I get the error:
invalid command \"x96

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

See [the JSON syntax.](https://www.json.org/) The keys and string values in JSON are enclosed in double quotes. The quotation marks in strings must be preceded by a "\" character:

```
select
'{
    "template_id": "OSBSheet",
    "name": "Exterior Wall Using 2\"x4\"x96\" Studs, Double Top Plate"
}'::jsonb

                                              jsonb                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"name": "Exterior Wall Using 2\"x4\"x96\" Studs, Double Top Plate", "template_id": "OSBSheet"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: I've changed that, I still get the same error, invalid command \"x96

Comment: Thanks, the issue was with other inserts above that were improperly formatted